# Embed the new twitter timeline - via the CP - error 500

Tags: control-panel, twitter, error-500

In a template (any template, EE 2.6.1) I try to add the new twitter timeline code (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-timelines)  but end up with an 500 error.

This is de twitter code:

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" data-dnt="true" href="https://twitter.com/the-username"  data-widget-id="MY-WIDGET-ID">Tweets by @the-username</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

When submitting the code I get an internal server error.

I tested the code, made a plain html file, uploaded via ftp, everything works perfect.
I use the exact same code: copy-paste it in a template and get the internal server error.

What can I do to get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up feeding the code directly to the database. I made sure to bypass the browser, which enable me to bypass the browser error.

It's really easy to bypass the browser, just enter the correct details in [coda](http://panic.com/coda/) or connect to your expression engine installation via [mountee](http://hellomountee.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that your server has `mod_security` enabled, which is detecting `script` tags in your `POST` and throwing a fit.

Disabling `mod_security` via `.htaccess` doesn't always work (you may have to contact your host instead), but you can try puttig this in the `.htaccess` file which resides in the same directory as your `admin.php` file (or EE system folder):

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. As you wrote, disabling mod_security via .htaccess didn't work. I ended up feeding the code directly to the database.